# How can I search on multiple geo_distance queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search on multiple locations with geo_distance query (using ES 7.3).
E.g.:

Search in Berlin +10km

Search in Munich +10km

And give me a combined result.

Basically I tried this here:

An array on `geo_distance` is not working. Would love to get some help on this :)

Comment: you can combine Geo-distance filter using should clause

Comment: Ahhh great thank you

Comment: Make an answer and you get credit if you wish :)

Comment: I have added a query as example of above use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example to search on multiple locations
Mapping:

```
PUT location
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties" : {
            "pin" : {
                "type" : "geo_point"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data:

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "location",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "rhn8f20BIb7c4jbYhr3Z",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "pin" : {
            "lat" : 40.73,
            "lon" : -74.1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "location",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "rxn8f20BIb7c4jbYz709",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "pin" : {
            "lat" : 40.717,
            "lon" : -73.99
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
GET location/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [    ---> multiple filters in should clause , either one of these has to be true
        {
          "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "1km",
                "pin" : {
                    "lat" : 40.73,
                    "lon" : -74.1
                }
            }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "1km",
                "pin" : {
                    "lat" : 40.717,
                    "lon" : -73.99
                }
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```