# how to run multiple geo_distance filter to get result for each filter separately?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need result documents based on geo_distance query for points A(lat=3,long=101) and B(lat=5,long=102) separately. one result docs I need corresponding to filter A(lat=3,long=101) and other result set I need corresponding to filter B(lat=5,long=102). I am not able to find the correct query for this. I found the query which provides union of results here - [How can I search on multiple geo_distance queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154471/how-can-i-search-on-multiple-geo-distance-queries) but here my requirement is to get results separately instead of union.

Comment: Could you please post the sample data & expected output?
Because from what I understand, your goal is the same as the union one

Answer (score 0):

You could use [filters aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) where the filter is geo_distance  query. That will divide results into buckets per filter. Then you could use [top hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to gather documents per bucket